# dynamo-client using local dynamodb client

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local

I'm trying to connect to my dynamodb local using the npm lib dynamo-client.  I have the local dynamodb client install and running as per: 
http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/09/dynamodb-local-for-desktop-development.html

However trying to connect to my localhost using:

```
db = dynamo.createClient('localhost', dbConf.credentials)
db.request('ListTables','', (e,r) -> console.log(e))
```

gives the following error:

```
e: {"code":"ECONNREFUSED","errno":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Needed to set the port and host in the options:

```
dbConf =
  region:
    region: 'localhost'
    host: 'localhost'
    port: 8000
  credentials:
    secretAccessKey: "KEY"
    accessKeyId: "ACCESSKEY"

db = dynamo.createClient(dbConf, dbConf.credentials)
```